# cgo panic when return pointer to C struct that contains a pointer

Tags: go, struct, lua, cgo, panic

I'm trying to build a small library written on Go for use with luajit. I can properly get what I want, until the struct which I return a pointer to contains pointers itself.

Go source:

```
package main
//typedef struct {
//  int     myint;
//  double  mydouble;
//  char*   mystring;
//} mystruct;
import "C"
import "fmt"
var myvar  C.mystruct
//export Init
func Init() {
    myvar.myint     = 1
    myvar.mydouble  = 2.0
    myvar.mystring  = C.CString("three")
    fmt.Println("myvar in go  : ", myvar.myint, myvar.mydouble, myvar.mystring)
}
//export GetVar
func GetVar() *C.mystruct {
    return &myvar
}
func main () {}
```

Lua source:

```
#! /usr/bin/luajit
local ffi   = require("ffi")
local go    = ffi.load("./golua.lib")
ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct {
    int     myint;
    double  mydouble;
    char*   mystring;
} mystruct;
extern void Init();
extern mystruct* GetVar();
]]
go.Init()
local var = go.GetVar()
print("myvar in lua : ", var.myint, var.mydouble, ffi.string(var.mystring))
```

Got this at runtime:

```
lionel@pc-lionel:~/go/src/tests/lua$ go build -buildmode=c-shared -o golua.lib *.go
lionel@pc-lionel:~/go/src/tests/lua$ ./gotest.lua 
myvar in go  :  1 2 0x55c17f41c360
panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
main._cgoexpwrap_86693eaa8e33_GetVar.func1(0xc420056ea8)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:95 +0x3c
main._cgoexpwrap_86693eaa8e33_GetVar(0x7ff15cccac60)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:97 +0x5b
Abandon (core dumped)
```

Note that the type of pointer does not matter, could be int* or whatever, it panics same way. I've also tried with GetVar returning an unsafe.Pointer instead with exact same result. In the example above I do not even need to assign a C.CString to mystring, cgo panics anyway.

For the purpose of my project, those C structures do not need to be modified on the lua side, especially not the strings, but need to be natively accessed for performance reasons.

Comment: I believe the error is referring to `myvar` itself, which is allocated on the Go heap, therefor `&myvar` is a go pointer which is candidate for garbage collection.  If there is no other Go code referencing the `myvar` value, the you can't guarantee the memory we remain allocated. (however unlikely garbage collection of the global value is, the cgo checks always err on the side of caution)

Comment: That was my first thought, but same code actually works if I remove char* mystring (or any pointer) from the struct. It seems I can workaround by allocating the struct myself with C.malloc, but then I've to manually compute the size of the struct.